# Cartesian product of n ranges

Tags: rust, combinatorics, cartesian-product, variadic, rust-itertools

I am rewriting a python program into rust and I am struggling to translate this line:

`itertools.product(range(0,8), repeat=n)`

What I am trying to achieve is something like this: https://pastebin.com/ceEA5E3q (but so that I can change the number of digits).

The yielded collections don't have to be tuples (or, even, they preferably shouldn't be tuples)

I tried writing a macro that would yield these iterators, since they work:

2 => `iproduct!(0..8, 0..8)`

3 => `iproduct!(0..8, 0..8, 0..8)`

4 => `iproduct!(0..8, 0..8, 0..8, 0..8)`

etc.

However, after a while I failed to create such macro.

I came up with this weird hack:

```
steps = 3;
for idx in 0..8_u128.pow(steps as u32) {
    let moves: Vec<u8> = format!("{:0fill$o}", idx, fill = steps)
        .chars()
        .map(|d| d.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u8)
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", moves);
}
```

I am creating a string that contains a zero-filled octal number, then iterate over digits and convert them into a `Vec` of numbers. While it works, I feel like doing all of these operations, especially with strings, affects my performance negatively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a function that creates a Cartesian product Iterator from an Iterator of Iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668915/how-to-create-a-function-that-creates-a-cartesian-product-iterator-from-an-itera)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`Itertools::multi_cartesian_product`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.multi_cartesian_product):

```
std::iter::repeat(0..8).take(n).multi_cartesian_product()
```

or

```
(0..n).map(|_| 0..8).multi_cartesian_product()
```